# Fire onclick event based on class of another div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript button that fires an onclick event but i only want it to do that if another div contains a class called "active".

so I have this structure:

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="someid1" class="design"></div>
<div id="someid2" class="design"></div>
<div id="someid3" class="design"></div>
<div id="someid4" class="design"></div>
</div>
```

that based on other page activity any can change to class="active"

```
<div id="someid2" class="design active">
```

The button is:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="dosomething">Click me</button>
```

but i only want the dosomething to work if the above any of the divs has the active class, and throw an alert if it does not. I am not terribly good with javascript and could use some help.

Hope this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Inside `dosomething` create an `if` that will check your condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `dosomething` is a function, you could just check for the class inside it

```
function dosomething() {
    if ( document.querySelector('#parentid .active') ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

`querySelector` returns `null` if not found, which is falsy.

[`document.querySelector` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Comment: dosomething is a function, so wouldn't i want to check for the absence of "active" and do throw an alert based on that?

Comment: You want to check if `#someid` has the class `active` and the way to do that is to try and select an element with that ID and that class, if something is selected, it exists, and as such the element has the `active` class? If you want to show an alert, go right ahead, just add an `else` statement, and alert away.

Comment: I see. it's a little more complicated because the active class would be on one of three or four divs that have different IDs. these divs are inside of another div that has it's own ID. What i am looking for is any div inside of another div with a class of "active". Hope that makes sense. I'll edit question

Comment: In that case, try to select an `.active` element inside the parent with it's own ID. I changed the code above to reflect that.